# How To handle JSON OBJECT where no idea about number if Objects and it's key name

Tags: android, json

I have a Json Object with key "propertyInformation" and the uder of this Object there are many Json Objects with diffrent values and in future that is possible the name of Json object changed or added new Json Object. My question is that how to parse that type JSON and what is the best way to display this data on screen.
My JSON is like show below but in future it will may be changed.

```
      {
          "Description": "You'll enjoy sitting on the front porch in the morning watching the sun come up while the many species of birds chirp and play. Inside features include Spanish tile in the living room, vaulted beam ceiling and stone fireplace. The master suite is enormous with enough room for a sitting area or office. There's also a window seat. Skylight in the guest bath for natural lighting. The large back patio and yard are great for entertaining, gardening or gathering pecans from the large pecan tree!",
          "MLS": "2649472",
          "Address": "802 Stillhouse SPG",
          "Lat": "30.51567",
          "Lng": "-97.73521",
          "NumberBathsTotal": "2",
          "NumberBedsTotal": "4",
          "Area": "RRW",
          "YearBuilt": "1979",
          "isFavourite": true,
          "propertyInformation": {
              "Essential Information": {
                  "MLS®#": "2649472",
                  "Price": "230000",
                  "Area": "RRW",
                  "Acres": "0.269",
                  "All Baths": "2",
                  "Full Baths": "2",
                  "Half Baths": "0",
                  "Total Beds": "4",
                  "Type": "Residential",
                  "SubType": "House",
                  "Status": "Active"
              },
              "Community Information": {
                  "Address": "802 Stillhouse SPG",
                  "City": "Round Rock",
                  "State": "TX",
                  "Zipcode": "78681",
                  "County": "Williamson",
                  "PID": "16346500060015",
                  "Sub Div": "Brushy Creek Sec 01 Or South"
              },
              "Amenities": {
                  "Address": "Electricity on Property, Natural Gas on Property",
                  "Number of Garage": "0",
                  "View": "No View",
                  "Fence": "Wood"
              },
              "Interior Information": {
                  "Interior Features": "Ceiling-Beam, Ceiling-Vaulted",
                  "Kitchen": "Galley Type",
                  "Appliances": "Dishwasher, Disposal, Microwave Oven, Range-Free Standing",
                  "Pool on Property": "No",
                  "Sprinkler System": "No",
                  "Rooms": "Converted Garage",
                  "Heating": "Central Heat",
                  "AC": "Central Air"
              },
              "Exterior Information": {
                  "Exterior Features": "Curbs, Deck, Outbuildings, Patio-Covered, Sidewalk",
                  "Roof": "Composition Shingle",
                  "Appliances": "Dishwasher, Disposal, Microwave Oven, Range-Free Standing",
                  "Number of Stories": "1",
                  "Number of Living": "1",
                  "Construction": "3 Side Masonry",
                  "Flooring": "Carpet, Linoleum, Tile - Hard"
              },
              "School Information": {
                  "School District": "Round Rock ISD",
                  "Elementary School": "Brushy Creek",
                  "Middle School": "Cedar Valley",
                  "High School": "McNeil"
              },
              "Tax Information": {
                  "Estimated Taxes": "5733",
                  "Tax Year": "2017",
                  "Tax Rate": "2.5",
                  "HoaFee": "$300 \/ Annually"
              },
              "Extra Information": {
                  "Legal Description": "BRUSHY CREEK SEC 1 (OR SOUTH), BLOCK 6, LOT 15",
                   "Address": "Fee-Simple",
                   "Square Foot Total": "1900",
                   "Square Foot Price": "Owner",
                   "Per Sqft Price": "121.05",
                   "Master Main": "Yes",
                   "Flood Plain": "No",
                   "Master Desc": "Full Bath",
                   "Sewer": "MUD",
                   "Water Source": "MUD"
               }
          }
     }
```

Comment: you can use `JsonNode` and  `ObjectMapper` which is iterate your random data.

Comment: You can iterate through keys of the JSONObject, and show teir values regardless of their number